# How to pad field with blank spaces using calculate field tool of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator

[image][image]I am trying to pad the right side of a field with blank spaces so that when I label the field, it labels further over to the left. The only way that I can seem to make this work so far is by adding a character that arc recognizes, such as a period at the end, otherwise the spaces are not recognized as characters and the label does not move. Any ideas how I can make this work without adding a period or something to the end?

The first image is what it looks like when I label it -  not what I want! The second is what I want to do, label to the left/bottom of the line, but as you can see there is a period at the end of it, which I don't want.

This is the field calculation that I am using, I am sure there must be a better way of doing it.

[image: the field calculation that I am using]

Comment: Why don't you just offset your label???

Comment: @Stacey, your description indicates there are more images (what you want, what you have), can you edit your post to upload the additional ones?

Comment: I am using a grid to label it, I just made this grid for Saskatchewan, and we already have a grid like this for Alberta which labels correctly- I can tell that there are spaces at the end of the Twp field in the Alberta one so I was hoping to use the same grid and just source to the saskatchewan shapefile. I did try to see if I could offset the label but there didn't seem to be any option in the grid to do that

Comment: @Stacey With Maplex you will be able to add an offset and use more options to place your label. Activate Maplex via the Labeling toolbar > Labeling menu.

Answer (score 5):

There are better ways to adjust label placement in the placement properties.  However, you can pad text using the python parser and [.ljust()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html).

```
"Twp1".ljust(10)
```

Comment: Thanks @Aaron I got that to work and label correctly on the grid, now I would like to field calculate all of the townships at once by using the TWP field which contains only the unique township number for each. I was trying to add the TWP field like this: "Twp" + !TWP!.ljust(20) and like this: "Twp + !TWP!".ljust(20)                                   for my string, but it keeps giving me an error

Comment: "Twp & !TWP!".ljust(20) this gave me almost what I wanted, but with the & sign in the middle

Comment: and I answered my question.... just remove the & sign. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using the python parser, look at [ljust()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_ljust.htm) (added as answer, not comment, to include link).

Comment: @Aaron, beat me to it...

Comment: You can include links in comments if you like. See the [help page](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for available markup, but the basic format is [text](link). While I'm at it... do you have two accounts? I sometimes see another recurvata with a different icon that hasn't signed on in a *long* while. If so, you might want to see about [merging them](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Thanks, did not know that. I've never seen a link in a comment, and have seen others write an answer in order to link. Good to know.